# Splitting strings in C using strtok

Tags: c, string, split, strtok

I am very confused about C strings.

I have an array of strings which has 18 elements: **char user[18][50]**, where each element has strings in the format of **"XXXX:YYYY:ZZZZ"**

But I only need the ZZZZs, and I want to store them in, say, **char z[18][50]** rather than **char *z** for consistency (also not really clear about char *)

So I'm using strtok to split the string

```
char *split;
char *temp;
for (i=0; i<18; i++){
  temp = user[i];
  split = strtok(temp, ":");

  //Wanna do something here
}
```

So I guess at each iteration **split** is a pointer that points to an array of string, elements being: **XXXX** and **YYYY** and **ZZZZ** separately.

How can I only get ZZZZs and store them into **char z[18][50]**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you'll call strtok twice again to get it,

```
for (i=0; i<18; i++){
  temp = user[i];
  split = strtok(temp, ":");
  split = strtok(NULL, ":");
  split = strtok(NULL, ":");
  // Now split is pointing to ZZZZ    

  //Wanna do something here
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I successfully stored them in **char z[18][50]** by doing
`strcpy(z[k], split)`
Now I would like to attach AB in front of all ZZZZs, to get something like ABZZZZZ. I tried
`char ABz[18][50];
....
strcat(ABz[k], "AB");
strcat(ABz[k], z[k]);
...`
And it works but when I print it out some (not all, like 4 of them) have some garbage in front of the AB, like &!@ABZZZZZ.
Do you know what's causing that?

Comment: @user2931670: try this, **sprintf(ABz[k], "%s%s", "AB", split);**

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The `rindex` [function is more suitable](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/rindex/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
int  main() {
    char *split;
    char buffer[256];
    char temp[] = "XXXX:YYYYY:ZZZZZ";
    split = rindex(temp, ':') + 1;
    strcpy(buffer, split);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;    

}
```